# Add multiple elements to xml with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to add some child elements in to the parent element of xml tree.
Source XML is:

```xml
<catalog>
    <element>
        <collection_list />
    </element>
    <element>
        <collection_list />
    </element>
</catalog>
```

I've tried following code in python 3:

```py
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('source.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

elementCollections = tree.xpath('/catalog/element/collection_list')

for element in elementCollections:
    childElement = etree.SubElement(element, "collection")
    listOfElementCollections = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

    for elementCollection in listOfElementCollections:
        childElement.text = elementCollection

newtree = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8')
newtree = newtree.decode("utf-8")
print(newtree)
```

but instead of:

```xml
<catalog>
    <element>
        <collection_list>
            <collection>c1</collection>
            <collection>c2</collection>
            <collection>c3</collection>
        </collection_list>
    </element>
    <element>
        <collection_list>
            <collection>c1</collection>
            <collection>c2</collection>
            <collection>c3</collection>
        </collection_list>
    </element>
</catalog>
```

i have such result:

```xml
<catalog>
    <element>
        <collection_list>
            <collection>c3</collection>
        </collection_list>
    </element>
    <element>
        <collection_list>
            <collection>c3</collection>
        </collection_list>
    </element>
</catalog>
```

Please explain me how to insert multiple elements in tree.

EDIT:
Fixed name of tag for "childElement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the collection in the inner for loop, not the outer:

```
for element in elementCollections:
    listOfElementCollections = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

    for elementCollection in listOfElementCollections:
        childElement = etree.SubElement(element, "collection")
        childElement.text = elementCollection

newtree = etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8')
newtree = newtree.decode("utf-8")
print newtree
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This code:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('source.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

elementCollections = tree.xpath('/catalog/element/collection_list')

for element in elementCollections:
    childElement = etree.SubElement(element, "collectionName")
    listOfElementCollections = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

    for elementCollection in listOfElementCollections:
        childElement2 = etree.SubElement(childElement, "collection")
        childElement2.text = elementCollection

newtree = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8')
newtree = newtree.decode("utf-8")
print(newtree)
```

You need to create new element in the loop.

Comment: Thank you for help, Ali! You are right. Note: I've fixed mistake in name of childElement's tag, and so you can fix it in 8 line of code too